# managing multiple node child processes

Tags: node.js, child-process

How can I manage multiple concurrent child processes that have been forked?

In this example, `start_child()` can be invoked multiple times, and each invocation can run indefinitely.  When forking an arbitrary number of child processes like this, how can I communicate with / address each individual child process?  Let's say I have 3 forked child processes running, and they keep running indefinitely, but I want to kill (or send a message to) child process number 2.  How would I do that?

If `stop_child()` is invoked, it kills all of the currently running child processes.  How do I refactor this code so that I can call `stop_child()` on an individual child process?

```
let app     = require('express')();
let server  = require('http').Server(app);
let io      = require('socket.io')(server);
let fork    = require('child_process').fork;

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('start_child', function () {
        start_child();
    });

    socket.on('stop_child', function () {
        child.kill();
    }
}

function start_child() {
    child = fork('./child_script.js');

    //conditional logic to either run
    //start_child() again or let it end
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried this, based on some of the comments.  But if I launch 3 processes and then call, for example, `child[0].kill()`, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'kill' of undefined`.  I'm guessing my problem is that I'm not correctly passing the `i` variable to the `io.on()` call:

```
let app     = require('express')();
let server  = require('http').Server(app);
let io      = require('socket.io')(server);
let fork    = require('child_process').fork;
let i       = 0;
let child   = [];

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('start_child', function (i) {
        start_child(i++);
    });

    //this is hard coded just for testing
    socket.on('stop_child', function () {
        child[0].kill();
    }
}

function start_child(i) {
    child[i] = fork('./child_script.js');

    //conditional logic to either run
    //start_child() again or let it end
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Okay, I figured out that I need to send the incrementing variable from the client side, passed through an object coming from the `emit` call.  Now when I call `child[0].kill()` there is no error.  The problem is that the child process is not killed:

server.js

```
let app     = require('express')();
let server  = require('http').Server(app);
let io      = require('socket.io')(server);
let fork    = require('child_process').fork;

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('start_child', function (count) {
        let num = count.count;
        start_child(num);
    });

    //this is hard coded just for testing
    socket.on('stop_child', function (count) {
        let num = count.count;
        child[num].kill();
    }
}

function start_child(num) {
    child[num] = fork('./child_script.js');

    //conditional logic to either run
    //start_child() again or let it end
}
```

index.html

```
$(function () {
    let socket  = io();
    let i       = 0;

    $('#start').on('click', function () {
        socket.emit('start_child', {"count": i++});
    });

    $('#stop').on('click', function () {
        //the count is hard coded here just for testing purposes
        socket.emit('stop_child', {"count": 0});
    });
});
```

---

**FINAL UPDATE - WITH RESOLUTION**

Resolution #2 (right above this) is actually the solution.  The problem I was having after that (where the `child.kill()` call didn't seem to do anything) was caused by a piece of the code that I had left out (in the code comment: 'conditional logic to either run start_child() again or let it end').

This is what was in there:

```
if (condition) {
    setTimeout(start_child, 5000);
} else {
    console.log('this child process has ended');
}
```

And this is what I changed it to (basically, I just had to pass the incrementing variable to the `start_child()` function so that it would have the same place in the `child` array when it restarted):

```
if (condition) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        start_child(num)
    }, 5000);
} else {
    console.log('this child process has ended');
}
```

Comment: What OS is your server running on and what is your child_script doing.  It says this in the doc for `child.kill()`: ***Note that while the function is called kill, the signal delivered to the child process may not actually terminate the process.***  You should also be logging `child.on('error', ...)` in case there is an error delivering the kill message.

Comment: Currently, it's running in a Cygwin environment on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork()` returns a ChildProcess object which has methods and events on that object for interprocess communication with that process.  So you have to save each ChildProcess object from when you call `start_child()` and then use the appropriate object in order to communicate with the other process.

You can see events and methods of the ChildProcess object [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess).  There are also numerous code examples.

Comment: I understand that `fork()` returns a ChildProcess object, and I've read the documentation.  I'm just not clear on how to address a specific child object (when multiple children have been forked), or how I would need to refactor the example code to make that happen.

Comment: @CJG - It's hard to understand what the problem is.  If you open 5 child processes, you can keep those in an array.  To communicate with the first one, you get the `ChildProcess` object from the first element of the array and you use that specific `ChildProcess` object to communicate with that specific child.

Comment: @CJG - Are you trying to send a message from parent to a specific child or from one specific child to another specific child?

Comment: @CJG - Your `start_child()` function should put each child that it opens into an array that lives at a higher scope such that you can access that array later when you want to communicate with one of the child processes.

Comment: I'm trying to send a message from parent to a specific child.  Specifically, I'm trying to send `child.kill()` to a specific child.  If I launch two processes, then want to kill only the first one, how do I do that?  I updated my question with what was my attempt to do what you said, but it's still not quite right.

Comment: I added a second update.  I figured out how to put each process into an array, so I have `child[0]`, `child[1]`, `child[2]`, etc.. running.  But when I call `child[0].kill()`, for example, the child is not killed.  There's no error, though.  It just seems like nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

In order to send message to the child process, use the following example :

parent.js

**

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');
const forked = fork('child.js');
forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});
forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

**

child.js

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  process.send({ counter: counter++ });
}, 1000);
```

For further information refer this article :

https://medium.freecodecamp.com/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a

Comment: I know how to send messages back and forth between the parent and the child.  What I don't know is how to send a message to a specific child when the parent has multiple children.

Comment: You need to do some remembering of the child nodes at parent side like storing the child objects in an array and then call the appropriate child object methods

Comment: Can you give me a simple example?  I need to be able to call `kill()` on a specific child.  As the code is currently written, if I call `child.kill()`, then all child processes are killed.  I get that each child node has to be remembered on the parent side; I'm just not quite sure how to do that with this code.

Comment: I do not much have idea about your exact requirement , but i think following can be done :                                                                           
var array = {};
array["child1"] = forked1;
array["child2"] = forked2;
array["child3"] = forked3;

array["child1"].kill();